# Python program should not calculate float length, only string

Tags: python, string, calculator, string-length

I am creating a function in Python to calculate the length of a string, while letting the user know that Int and float is not a string. The Int section works, however the function does not respect the float and I do not know why.

I am using visual Studio Code in Windows 10.
Python 3.7.0 [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

```
def length_string(mystring):
  try:
    if type(int(mystring)) == int:
       return f"Hello, this is not {mystring} a string"
    elif type(mystring) == float:
       return f"Hello, this is not {mystring} a string"
    elif type(str(mystring)) == str:
       return len(mystring)
  except:
    return len(mystring)
```

string_name = input("Please enter your value: ")
print(length_string(string_name))`

Result String Hello is: 5
Result  Int 555 = Hello, this is not 555 a string
Result Float 555.0 = 5, but should be the same as the int.

Comment: string_name = input("Please enter your value: ")
print(length_string(string_name))

Comment: A float will be rounded by `int` and will therefore never make it past your first if.

Comment: `type(int(mystring)) == int` is always either True, or raises a ValueError - there is no possibility of reaching either of the following `elif`s.  After explicitly converting the string to an `int`, there's not much point in checking whether than `int` is an `int`!

Comment: I've tested your program and it does not do what you say it does. Inputting 555.5 still causes the output to be "Hello, this is not 555.0 a string"

Answer (score 0):

Float raises a value error in the first if block. Since you are only returning the length if the variable is a string, you can do it more efficiently with single comparison.

```
def length_string(mystring):
     if isinstance(mystring, basestring):
          return len(mystring);
     else:
          return f"Hello, {mystring} is not a string";
```

Answer (score -1):

If the conversion of the string `int(mystring)` succeeds, the type is always a string, otherwise the `execpt`-block is executed, so the two `elif`-blocks never gets executed.

```
def length_string(mystring):
    try:
        float(mystring)
    except ValueError:
        return f"Hello, this is not {mystring} a string"
    return len(mystring)
```